# Start with 10 dices, and after each round of throwing, we remove the one with number 6, and repeat process.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We start with 10 dices and throw all of them in every turn. When one or more has number 6 on it after throw, we remove them, and repeat process with new amount of dices. Game ends when there are no dices left.

What's probability that game will end after up to 10 rounds?

What's probability that game will end in 10th round?

First question:
chance that given dice will survive ten round is $(5/6)^{10}$. So chance that it will be removed in first ten rounds is $(1-(5/6)^{10})$. We have ten dices, and fortune of each one is independent of the others, so probability we are looking for is $(1-(5/6)^{10})^{10}$.

I am not sure how to approach second question.

Can it be that first, same as above, we find probability that game lasts up to 9 rounds (first question was about 10 rounds), which is $(1-(5/6)^9)^{10}$ and then find probability that some.

Then we find probability that game will last more than 10 rounds. We know that probability that it will last up to 11 rounds is $(1-(5/6)^{11})^{10}$, so we need negation of it, which is $1-(1-(5/6)^{11})^{10}$.

Now if game lasts exactly 10 rounds is $1$$-$(probability that game lasts up to 9 rounds)$-$(probability that game lasts more than 10 rounds)$=1-(1-(5/6)^9)^{10}-(1-(1-(5/6)^{11})^{10})$

Is it roughly correct?

Comment: It's correct. Though it would be easier to take the probability that the game last up to 9 rounds, and multiply it by the probability that some dice gets a six.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restating your argument with $n$ rounds and $m$ dice:

- The probability a particular die lasts at least $n$ rounds is $(5/6)^{n}$
- The probability a particular die is removed by the $n$th round is $1-(5/6)^{n}$
- The probability all $m$ dice are removed by the $n^{\text{th}}$ round is $(1-(5/6)^{n})^{m}$.
- The probability all $m$ dice are removed by the $n-1^{\text{th}}$ round is $(1-(5/6)^{n-1})^{m}$.
- The probability the game ends in the $n^{\text{th}}$ round is $(1-(5/6)^{n})^{m}-(1-(5/6)^{n-1})^{m}$.

So your answer to the first part is correct, with $n=m=10$ giving $(1-(5/6)^{10})^{10}$

Your answer for the second part is not quite correct for $n=m=10$, and you should have given $(1-(5/6)^{10})^{10}-(1-(5/6)^{9})^{10}$